# symfony & translation : How to translate standard expressions & forms?

Tags: symfony, translators

New to Symfony I created a login form (make:auth) and installed the translator.
I added in my form template login.html.twig

```
    {% block body %}
    <h1>{% trans %}Hello{% endtrans %}</h1>
    <form method="post">
...
```

and defined in translations directory a messages.fr.yml, containing Hello : Bonjour.

That works and when I display my form, hello is well translated to Bonjour

But, all the other labels are not translated (username, password, etc)

which seems to be logical as the entries do not have the `{% trans %} {% endtrans %}` commands

```
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
<label for="inputUsername" class="sr-only">Username</label>
```

question 1 : is there a way to automatically translate all these labels?

question 2 : is there existing translation files containing all the standard used messages / labels?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

to manage the translation in twig there is the appropriate trans function (example):

```
<label for="inputUsername" class="sr-only">{{'username' | trans}}</label>
```

and in your messages.fr.yml add:

username: "Nom d'utilisateur"

Comment: thank you for the answer. May I do it manually for all the inputs or is there a magic symfony function do that automatically ?

Comment: maybe you can search for generic online messages.fr.yml but I've never tried them.
you will still be forced to look at the content and report the exact path in the various twigs, so I presume it is better if you create it customized for your project.

Answer (score 0):

The default for form labels is to use a ["humanized"](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#humanize) version. And that one then may be translated in the `messages` translation domain.

You can change that by either setting the `label` on the form (element) directly, either in the builder

```
->add('fieldName', TextType::class, [
      'label' => 'fieldName_translation_key',
])
```

or in the template:

```
{{ form_row(form.fieldname, {label: 'fieldname_translation_key'}) }}

{# this also works with form_widget/form_label, depending on the form element #}
```

If you want to use keyword translations for fields, you can set the [`label_format`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#label-format) on the form itself (in the `configure` method, as an option) or on all its elements manually (with the [placeholders](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#label-format) described).

I personally prefer the `label_format` method because I rarely render the form "manually".

You can also set the `translation_domain` parameter to change the used translation domain (`messages`) to something else.